# In Visual Studio, how to visualize code line length for non-test code only?

Tags: visual-studio, text-editor

I'm using guidelines right now, but I do not think there is any way to disable them for certain projects (my project with tests).

In general, how do you reconcile long, descriptive test method names with a line length limit for non-test code (both of which I think are good)?  If you feel the same way and have solved this, what solution do you use?

Comment: Code line length limitation concept is obsolete. Drop it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We accomplish it by dropping the line length limit for all our projects that are not developed in a 1980s green screen environment. We instead use the full power of our 21st century high resolution LCD displays, bitmap screen modes and powerful IDEs to make source code that is descriptive and easy to maintain, rather then designed to fit into the screen and memory footprint of a machine whose RAM is measured in KBs.

(And then we beat the guy advocating line length limits and 3 letter variable names with a pointy stick)

Comment: Greater than about 100 char lines causes problems in side by side diffs even on large res monitors. I see the 80 char limit as an elegant width from a more civilized age

Comment: @rq that's why horizontal scrollbars were invented

Comment: I've reviewed code where I had to constantly horizontally scroll the diff to look at the differences.   Not fun.

Comment: Most modern IDEs have a word wrap feature. While the word wrap in Visual Studio is not my favorite (I prefer the word wrap in Crimson Editor where wrapped lines are given a slightly different background color, rather then Visual Studio's little glyph) it still gets the job done.

Comment: Can't agree. 1) Long lines make any text harder to read - here're some tips from a professional typographer: http://practicaltypography.com/line-length.html. 2) viewing multiple files side by side is very handy. Not possible with long lines. 3) Long lines are harder to navigate, e.g. try selecting some text with a mouse near the end of a long line - if the next / previous line is short and you accidentally move your mouse cursor outside of the current line, you'll lose your scroll position. Very annoying!

Comment: Talk to somebody who reads code through a braille display. They usually have a 40 character limit, 80 if your insurance is extra generous. Line length is an accessibility problem, not only for those of us who have to use a bigger font because our eyes are getting older.

Answer (score 7):

Drop the line length policy.

If you still want to insist on keeping track of the column, try adding the following to the registry if your using Visual Studio

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\Text Editor] "Guides"="RGB(192,192,192) 110"
```

RGB of course controls the color of the line, and you may change 110 to whatever number you like.

The end result gives you a guide line in Visual Studio so you always know where the column is, and the IDE ends up looking like this:
[alt text http://blogs.msdn.com/photos/shawnfa/images/659277/637x480.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/photos/shawnfa/images/659277/637x480.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Can't agree with the other answers that long lines are not an issue. You wouldn't say it's comfortable to read a minified single-line .js file - even with the horizontal scroll bars!

Visual Studio has an extension for adding visual hints - [Editor Guidelines](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.EditorGuidelines). You can manually create guidelines wherever you like - 80 or 120 characters. It does not enforce line lengths, so you are still free to deviate where you think it's appropriate.